# Load upselling block in custom controller

Tags: up-sells

I have created a custom controller and added the upselling block using the layout.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
   <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action> 
   <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action> 
</block>
```

however this results in the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getUpSellProductCollection() on
>   a non-object in
>   \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Upsell.php on line 49

Can anyone tell me what caused this error?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I have created a custon controller that loads a custom phtml file;

Comment: Then I have added a call to the block in my layout file like this: 

`<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
          <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
          <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
      </block>`
I get there an error message :
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getUpSellProductCollection() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Upsell.php on line 49

Answer (score 2):

---

Edit: Your updated question is more specific, and my previous answer doesn't really apply if you already have the block created.

You have **three** options.

**As suggested in the other answer, please don't edit the CORE Magento Class. This isn't tracked in source control usually, and it might cause problems later (especially if you ever do upgrade)**

**1) Set the product on the registry**
Specifically, like the other answer mentioned, your block can't pull a 'current product' from the registry.

```
protected function _prepareData()
{
    $product = Mage::registry('product'); /* This is not returning a valid product */
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    $this->_itemCollection = $product->getUpSellProductCollection()
        ->setPositionOrder()
        ->addStoreFilter()
    ;
...
```

Luckily, the Magento Registry is a global drop that you can set/access, explained in great detail by Alan Storm:
alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial

If you want to follow the other answer as far as editing the method with the product parameter, to call via xml or within your controller. You can:

**2) Extend the Magento Block in your own module.**
Then reference that block in your xml with the extra product parameter in the method.

**3) (probably overkill in this case) Setup a block class override via xml**
inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/
Then just call the same magento block the usual way, but it will load up your class (which still ends up extending the original).

2 & 3 rely on the other answer's solution, but the implementation is more future-proof, and cleaner to track.

4. Instead of editing the method to take a product parameter as suggested by the other answer, and extended upon by implementation recommendations from 2, and 3, you could also override the method preferably with method 2 and just change the line from

   $product = Mage::registry('product');
   to

   $product = Mage::registry('modulename-upsell-product');

That is probably less disruptive of an override, if you don't want to set 'product' for everything on your controller. You might have other blocks that depend on a product being set in the registry which might be a different product than being set for your upsell block.
d

---

**Previous Answer**

If you are looking to just create a block programatically, you can do that with the getLayout() method within your controller:

ie:

```
/**
 * Block Factory
 *
 * @param     string $type
 * @param     string $name
 * @param     array $attributes
 * @return    Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
 */
public function createBlock($type, $name='', array $attributes = array())
```

In this case:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_upsell', 'upsells')->setTemplate('relative-path-from-theme/to/file.phtml');
```

Stock phtml is catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml, but since you might like custom changes that would be different you can always copy this and place it somewhere, edit it, and then put the path in the setTemplate() method noted above.

I think would do the trick. You would still need to do something like attach this created block to the layout that is being outputted, or call toHtml() on the block itself if that's all you are after (somewhat dirty).

However, if you want to control the layout on your custom controller it's probably best to setup a layout handle for this as you might have more blocks on your custom layout page:

**1) Create a custom layout handle for your controller**

http://www.develodesign.co.uk/blog/item/143-layout-handles-in-magento-design
Summing up this blog post, you need to:

Identify the appropriate layout handle by:

```
var_dump($this->getLayout()->getHandles());
```

This will get you a list of the layout handles, the one to your interest is the "4th", contains your controller, index, and action. Magento is basically loading up blocks within these layout handles, from the various layout xml files in your app/design/frontend directory.

You can see the relevant layouts on a particular controller from the var_dump of the `getHandles()`.

2. Creating a layout xml file for your module with your handle (Optional)
   Loading a relevant handle can be done in your local.xml of your theme directory, but seeing as how you have a custom controller and if you foresee there being several pages, or you just want to be more organized you can create your own xml file to house your custom layout handles:

Creating your own layout xml file:
First code block under *Adding A New Layout File*, which adds some xml within your module's `/etc/config.xml`

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/30/introducing-magento-layout/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SmashingMagazine_Layout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </SmashingMagazine_Layout>
    </modules>
    
    <!-- we are making changes to the frontend -->
    <frontend>
        
        <!-- we are making changes to the layout -->
        <layout>
            
            <!-- we are adding a new update file -->
            <updates>
                
                <!-- 
                    this child node name must be
                    unique throughout Magento
                -->
                <smashingmagazine_layout 
                         module="SmashingMagazine_Layout">
                    
                    <!-- the name of the layout file we are adding -->
                    <file>smashingmagazine_layout.xml</file>
                    
                </smashingmagazine_layout>
                
            </updates>
            
        </layout>
        
    </frontend>

</config>
```

Please merge the sample xml above, particularly the layout tags, and children, with the xml into your module's /etc/config.xml within the  tags (which you may have to create if they don't exist), and making the necessary edits referencing the module name.

*Note about custom layout xml placement: If you did optional step #2. This, if you want, can be placed in base/default to made available to all themes, as it pertains to a module and not specifically to a theme. Though some magento .gitignore files and people suggest that base/default should be reserved for magento only, and it's a bad habit to develop. In any case putting your custom layout xml file can be done in app/design/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/layout/ or app/design/frontend/custompackage/base/default/*

*Note about local.xml file placement: If you did not do optional step #2 and opt for a local.xml, your local.xml will be in your custom theme ie: app/design/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/layout/, which could be something like app/design/frontend/sticksnglue/default/layout/local.xml  . If the local.xml doesn't exist you can create it*

3. Using the layout handle within a layout xml file (either your custom one created in optional step 2), or in a file named local.xml).
   Either in your local.xml or your custom xml file now you can add the block using the layout handle picked from step 1).

Using the example from the blog post and their layout handle:

```
<doodletool_index_index>
  <reference name="relevant-block-name"><!-- relevant block name to drop your block name -->
   <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="upsells" as="upsells" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml"> <!-- this is your upsell block -->
  </reference>
</doodletool_index_index>
```

Hope this provides some detail about using Magento's layout with your custom controller.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

THe upsells are retrieved from a product. This will probably the product in `Mage::registry('current_product')`.

Basically 2 options here.

**Edit the block class**
Edit the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell` class, method `_prepareData` to accept an argument to load a product. For example like this:

```
protected function _prepareData()
{
+  if (!is_null($this->getData('product_id'))
+  {
+     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getData('product_id'));
+  }
+  else
+  {
      $product = Mage::registry('product');
+  }

   [...]
}
```

Now you can set the product ID you want to use from the layout XML by adding the following to your block reference

```
<action method="setData"><name>product_id</name><value>3</value></action>
```

**Set the current product** Register a current_product in your controller in, for example, the `_construct` function. This way the upsell block will use the correct product to retrieve the upsell products.

Add the following code

```
Mage::register('current_product', Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(3));
```

Personally I would go for the first option since the second might have averse effects with stuff like the page title. Please move core files to the local code pool before editing or extend them from a custom extension.